# Invalid if then else syntax

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

```
    If {Command.payment_ind_vsl}= 'F' Then 
    'Completed'
Else If {Command.payment_ind_ci} = 'F' Then 
         'Completed'
Else If {Command.payment_ind_mi} = 'F' Then 
        'Completed'
     Else 
       'In Progress'
```

Below is an example output that i need

```
 payment_ind_vsl             payment_ind_ci            payment_ind_mi      status
       F                          F                          N              In Progress

       F                          F                          F              Complete
```

From the above example, if the payment is all 'F' than it return 'Complete'. If there is still 'N' in one of the payment it return 'In Progress'.

I have try some code from the site but the result is also an error. is there any other ways that i can try to solve it.

Comment: what is the error and what are the command.fields values?

Comment: @jambonick there is no error but when view it it the report, it only capture the first if statement other than that is no value.

Comment: is problem solved?

Comment: @reds still haven't solve .

Comment: try to use the answer below

Comment: @hunt please explain. The fields have no value but your formula still returns 'Completed'?

Comment: @jambonick i created another formula field name status to write the if statement, the payment field have value but the status formula return null

Comment: What are the data types of  payment_ind_vsl, payment_ind_ci and payment_ind_mi? Are they strings?

Comment: @jambonick yes string

Comment: Change all your quotes with double quotes, any improvement?

Answer (score 0):

If the fields in question aren't already string type, try casting them first. Either way you'll definitely want to use double quotes instead:

```
IF CSTR({Command.payment_ind_vsl}) = "F" OR
CSTR({Command.payment_ind_mi}) = "F" OR
CSTR({Command.payment_ind_ci}) = "F" THEN "Completed"
ELSE "In Progress"
```